# C-Sharp DateTime Culture format for SQL Date-Format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

Is there a culture for this date-format?

`2022-03-08 23:59:59`

Or do I have to do this manualy with `.ToString()`?

Comment: It's quite unclear what your question is. At best a culture has a particular default date/time format, but there is zero reason to look for one if you already know the exact format you want -- just use that format then. More to the point, if you pass a `DateTime` value as a `DateTime` (which most if not all database systems allow) you shouldn't need to care what it looks like as a string.

Comment: I thaught Cultures worked like a "format preset" and would make my code a bit prettier. Doesn't it?

Comment: In short, no, not really. Suppose this was the default format of, say, Bulgaria (it isn't), would it really make your code "prettier" to use the Bulgarian culture just for that? It would rather raise questions on what on earth Bulgaria is doing there, when instead you need the explicit format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` for this specific case.

Comment: Please note that if the database you're communicating with is SQL Server, that format is *not* safe in the sense that it isn't independent of language at the *server* side. A safe format would be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff` (but, like I've said, what you normally *really* want is to pass the value as a typed parameter, so the format isn't relevant).

Comment: SQL dates don't have a format, they are stored as binary. I suspect what you are doing is injecting the values directly into your query. Do *not* do this, use parameters instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it matter if there is a culture which ensures that `DateTime.ToString` will output this format? What matters is if you want to output a `DateTime` in a culturally appropriate format or not. If you don't care about a (given) culture, why do you ask for it?

If all you need is a `DateTime` as a string in that format, use:

```
string dtAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: There's a gotcha with the code here.  You should still pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, because the current culture might be using a calendar system other than Gregorian.  For example, if the current culture is `"ar-SA"`, you'll get the output in the same requested format, but the date part (for today) would be `1443-08-05` instead of `2022-03-08`.